# Allowing the user to undo a "don't ask again"?

Tags: android, permissions

In Android if you ask for permissions, second requests onward allow the user to check "Don't ask me again" so the failure state will always be reached in the future.

What if the user changes their mind and wants to allow permission, but can't now because the feature defaults to the permission-fail state? How can the user undo their "don't ask again" setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user cannot undo the "don't ask again" setting itself directly. The user can:

- Grant rights to the permission group through the Settings app (Settings > Apps > (your app) > Permissions), or
- Clear the data associated with your app, which AFAIK will clear the "don't ask again" status (along with everything else related to permissions), or
- Uninstall and reinstall the app (which definitely resets all state related to permissions)

Answer (score 0):

The user can access the App-info screen for the app and change permissions there even if he hit "don't ask again".

Example Image:
[image]